# Handling virtual keyboard close event on windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, xaml, keyboard

I'm developing universal windows application and stuck with keyboard closing possibility on win 10. When I get object focused keyboard is appeared and if focus lost keyboard hiding, it's clear, but if I tap keyboard closing button focus still on object, so code attached to lost focus event didn't executes. Is it way to handle keyboard close event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by handling InputPane::Hiding event [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.inputpane.hiding?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)